# Find out with a command if we can listen on a port

Tags: linux, networking

It is possible with a simple Unix command to find out if we can listen on a port or not? I'm building an application in which the user has the permissions to change the port.

I have to check though if the port is already listening somewhere or not. I want it in Command since i can't use any programming language for other reasons.

Thanky you

Answer (score 1):

To check if a port is not already binding using [netcat](/questions/tagged/netcat) :

```
$ nc -zw2 <IP> <PORT> && echo "already binding" || echo "Not already binding"
```

Reminder, users can only use ports > 1024 and < 65536